# GWT Void remote services fail for seemingly no reason

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm working on a GWT project and have several void remote services that seem to execute just fine, but on the client side, end up firing the `onFailure()` method.  No exceptions are thrown anywhere, and the expected behavior is observed on the backend.  I have no idea what could be going wrong.  Here is the relevant code:

Interfaces and implementation...

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("DeleteSearchService")
public interface DeleteSearchService extends RemoteService {
    /**
     * Utility class for simplifying access to the instance of async service.
     */
    public static class Util {
        private static DeleteSearchServiceAsync instance;
        public static DeleteSearchServiceAsync getInstance(){
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = GWT.create(DeleteSearchService.class);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void delete(SearchBean search);
}

public interface DeleteSearchServiceAsync {
    public void delete(SearchBean bean, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
}

public class DeleteSearchServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements DeleteSearchService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void delete(SearchBean search) {
        try {

            Connection conn = SQLAccess.getConnection();
            String sql = "DELETE FROM `searches` WHERE `id`=?";

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, search.getSearchId());

            ps.execute();

            sql = "DELETE FROM `searchsourcemap` WHERE `search-id` = ?";

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, search.getSearchId());

            ps.execute();

            return;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Log error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Calling code...

```
private class DeleteListener implements ClickListener {
        public void onClick(Widget sender) {
            DeleteSearchServiceAsync dss = DeleteSearchService.Util.getInstance();

            SearchBean bean = buildBeanFromGUI();

            dss.delete(bean, new AsyncCallback<Void>(){

                //@Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // TODO log
                    SearchNotDeleted snd = new SearchNotDeleted();
                    snd.show();
                }

                //@Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    SearchDeleted sd = new SearchDeleted();
                    sd.show();
                    searchDef.getParent().removeFromParent();                   
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

I know I'm a jerk for posting like 500 lines of code but I've been staring at this since yesterday and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  Maybe a 2nd set of eyes would help...

Thanks,
brian

Comment: What is the value of the caught variable passed to the onFailure method in your AsyncCallback?

Answer (score 0):

LGTM I'm afraid.

Are you using the hosted mode or a full-fledged browser? You can try switching and see if it helps.

Also, it might help listening to that `//TODO` and perform a `GWT.log` when `onFailure` is invoked.